# Is there a way to dispose or pop a widget after certain delay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to dispose my loading animation after some time has passed, is there any way I could achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide your code

Comment: if you just want to wait before executing a function try using `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30));` before calling the function

Answer (score 0):

You can change a widget in setState:

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  Widget _loading = Container(child: Text("loading"));

  Future<void> _removeLoading() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30));
    setState(() {
      _loading = Container();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _removeLoading();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _loading,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Or have a boolean variable change the state:

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  boool _loading = true;

  Future<void> _stopLoading() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30));
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _stopLoading();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: child: loading ? YourLoadingWidget : NotALoadingWidget
    );
  }
```